# How do I keep my static hostname from changing?

Tags: fedora, hostname

I'm plagued with an issue. On occasion my transient hostname changes from localhost to the name of my mom's laptop, an entirely different machine. It started doing this a few days ago and I'm not sure what I did that could cause it to do that. It changes back to the default localhost at random but frequents back to the name of my mom's laptop. It doesn't matter that I set my hostname manually when it does this. I'm using Fedora and I can't seem to find any similar issues so I presume that it's a setting I'm unaware of or a one of a kind problem.

Edit: I meant transient, not static.

Comment: Your hostname is never "localhost", it's the other way round: "localhost" is a special hostname to refer to 127.0.0.1. You haven't told us how you discovered that "your static hostname changes", but DHCP can assign hostnames, so it's possible that you've configured your router to do that. Your static hostname is defined in `/etc/hostname`, and unless that file actually changes because you've installed some software that changes it for whatever reason, that name is static. (And you shouldn't enter "localhost" in there, that just doesn't work).

Comment: I beg to differ. The @ changes, on the command prompt. And running 'hostname' in the terminal reveals that it changes as well. My hostname has always been localhost since the day I installed Fedora, until recently.

Comment: Also, I meant transient, not static

Comment: How are you setting your hostname manually? And are you explicitly setting it to `localhost`? That might be a problem...at least in older revisions of Fedora, the names `localhost` and `localhost.localdomain` meant "I have not set a hostname on this system so you should use whatever the DHCP server tells you".

Comment: With hostnamectl. I've given up on it pretty much, tbh. Annoying to have to do it. consistently. As I said, it's always been localhost for me, or at least the command-prompt showed it as localhost. I never had a reason to actually check the hostname before.